# Definite Integral of $\sin 2\pi x $

Tags: definite-integrals

I'm trying to find:

$$\int_0^{1} \sin 2\pi x \; dx =$$

My friend says the result should be zero. Is there any graphical way to prove it.

Comment: How have u achieved the result?

Comment: The strangest result someone gets by hand.

Comment: The result is exactly $0$ because $\int_0^1\sin{2\pi x}dx=(1/2\pi)(\cos{0}-\cos{2\pi})$. Looks like your result is a numerical approximation which is almost $0$ to the $10^{-5}$

Comment: Just from heuristic reasoning, we see that the area under the curve from $0$ to $1/2$ is equal to, and opposite in sign from the area under the curve from $1/2$ to $1$.

Comment: Perhaps you could delete this post.

Comment: It says "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?" What choices do I have?

Comment: @Gin99, I doubt you can delete a question with an upvoted answer.

Comment: @Zaid Alyafeai, is it possible for you to close it? Please

Comment: I voted to close. One more vote and it will be closed.

Comment: @Zaid Alyafeai. Thanks. At the others Please vote to close. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried graphing the function?

[image: picture]

Intuitively, what should the answer be? Because the area from $0$ to $0.5$ and the area from $0.5$ to $1$ effectively cancel each other out, the answer is $0$.

The difference between your answer and your friend's answer may be due to rounding errors.

As @marwalix pointed out,  $\int_0^1 \sin(2\pi x)dx=(\frac{1}{2\pi})(\cos(0)−\cos(2\pi))$. Note that $(\cos(0)−\cos(2\pi)) = (1 - 1) = 0$. Then, since we are multiplying by $0$, the answer is also exactly $0$.

Comment: Can I know what software did you use to generate the graphic?

Comment: @Gin99 you can use this https://www.geogebra.org/graphing

Comment: @Gin99 I used Desmos, but any online graphing calculator will work.